# Implementation of first Pass in Bubble sort

Tags: algorithm, haskell

```
bubblesort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
bubblesort (x:y:xs)
    | x > y = y : bubblesort (x:xs)
    | otherwise = x : bubblesort (y:xs)
bubblesort (x) = (x)
```

1.I don't understand the last line of the code; I tried to comment it out and the compiler says " Non-exhaustive patterns in function bubblesort", and when I tried to move it to the first line of the code, the compile says "Pattern match is redundant." And the way it used round brackets confused me.

2.I tried to change the type declaration as bubblesort :: (Ord Int) => [Int] -> [Int] and I got another error " Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Ord Int (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)". Is there any way I can declare the list as an integer list?
.

Comment: `Ord a` says that `a` must be a member of the type class `Ord`. Members of the type class `Ord` can be ordered. If you are sure, that you only want to sort arrays of Int you might write `bubblesort :: [Int]->[Int]` instead.

The last line is necessary, as `bubblesort (x:y:xs)` expects an array containing at least two elements, namely `x` and `y`. At the end of the recursion `bubblesort` is called on an one element array. That causes the trouble.

Still calling `bubblesort []` would be a problem, as you didn't considered the empty case.

Comment: side note: I think your algorithm is incorrect - try `bubblesort [10,9..1]`

Answer (score 1):

1. The pattern `(x:y:xs)` matches with a list starting with `x` and `y`, and them continuing with the tail `xs`. So, it matches only with lists having at least length two. The other cases must be considered, otherwise the function will be a partial one and will crash at runtime as soon a short list is met.

   A possible way to fix this could be adding the two missing cases:

   ```
   bubblesort (x:[]) = x:[]   -- length 1
   bubblesort [] = []         -- length 0
   ```

   but it's simpler to just add one case at the end

   ```
   bubblesort xs = xs
   ```

   where `xs` is any list which was not handled by the cases above, i.e. a list whose length is less than two.
2. The type signature `bubblesort :: (Ord Int) => [Int] -> [Int]` is a bit weird. It states "if integers can be ordered, then `bubblesort` has type ...". We know that integers can be ordered, there's no need to require that. If you really want a more precise signature, just use

   ```
   bubblesort :: [Int] -> [Int]
   ```

   (But what's wrong with the more general signature? I'd stick to that one)